# Recursively mapped nested JSON but components do not render

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I recursively mapped nested JSON, and console log output all elements in format: property => value correctly, but components do not render. Following is JSON:

```
{
    "index": "dwarf",
    "name": "Dwarf",
    "speed": 25,
    "ability_bonuses": [
        {
            "ability_score": {
                "index": "con",
                "name": "CON",
                "url": "/api/ability-scores/con"
            },
            "bonus": 2
        }
    ],
    "alignment": "Most dwarves are lawful, believing firmly in the benefits of a well-ordered society. They tend toward good as well, with a strong sense of fair play and a belief that everyone deserves to share in the benefits of a just order.",
    "age": "Dwarves mature at the same rate as humans, but they're considered young until they reach the age of 50. On average, they live about 350 years.",
    "size": "Medium",
    "size_description": "Dwarves stand between 4 and 5 feet tall and average about 150 pounds. Your size is Medium.",
    "starting_proficiencies": [
        {
            "index": "battleaxes",
            "name": "Battleaxes",
            "url": "/api/proficiencies/battleaxes"
        },
        {
            "index": "handaxes",
            "name": "Handaxes",
            "url": "/api/proficiencies/handaxes"
        },
        {
            "index": "light-hammers",
            "name": "Light hammers",
            "url": "/api/proficiencies/light-hammers"
        },
        {
            "index": "warhammers",
            "name": "Warhammers",
            "url": "/api/proficiencies/warhammers"
        }
    ],
    "starting_proficiency_options": {
        "choose": 1,
        "type": "proficiencies",
        "from": [
            {
                "index": "smiths-tools",
                "name": "Smith's tools",
                "url": "/api/proficiencies/smiths-tools"
            },
            {
                "index": "brewers-supplies",
                "name": "Brewer's supplies",
                "url": "/api/proficiencies/brewers-supplies"
            },
            {
                "index": "masons-tools",
                "name": "Mason's tools",
                "url": "/api/proficiencies/masons-tools"
            }
        ]
    },
    "languages": [
        {
            "index": "common",
            "name": "Common",
            "url": "/api/languages/common"
        },
        {
            "index": "dwarvish",
            "name": "Dwarvish",
            "url": "/api/languages/dwarvish"
        }
    ],
    "language_desc": "You can speak, read, and write Common and Dwarvish. Dwarvish is full of hard consonants and guttural sounds, and those characteristics spill over into whatever other language a dwarf might speak.",
    "traits": [
        {
            "index": "darkvision",
            "name": "Darkvision",
            "url": "/api/traits/darkvision"
        },
        {
            "index": "dwarven-resilience",
            "name": "Dwarven Resilience",
            "url": "/api/traits/dwarven-resilience"
        },
        {
            "index": "stonecunning",
            "name": "Stonecunning",
            "url": "/api/traits/stonecunning"
        },
        {
            "index": "dwarven-combat-training",
            "name": "Dwarven Combat Training",
            "url": "/api/traits/dwarven-combat-training"
        },
        {
            "index": "tool-proficiency",
            "name": "Tool Proficiency",
            "url": "/api/traits/tool-proficiency"
        }
    ],
    "subraces": [
        {
            "index": "hill-dwarf",
            "name": "Hill Dwarf",
            "url": "/api/subraces/hill-dwarf"
        }
    ],
    "url": "/api/races/dwarf"
}
```

Then this is code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { Grid, Header, Label } from 'semantic-ui-react'

import TypeComponent from './type_component'
import TestComponent from './test_component'

class raceWindow extends Component {
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            data: {}
        }
    }

    componentDidMount()
    {
        fetch(this.props.hdAPI)
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then(data => {this.setState({data: data})});
        this.setState({hdAPI: this.props.hdAPI});
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps)
    {
        if(this.props.hdAPI !== prevProps.hdAPI)
        {
            fetch(this.props.hdAPI)
            .then(response=>response.json())
            .then(data => {this.setState({data: data})});
            this.setState({hdAPI: this.props.hdAPI});
        }
    }

    isType (attr, value)
    {
        if(Array.isArray(value))
        {
            value.map((v) => {
                Object.entries(v).map(([a1,v1]) => this.isType(a1,v1))
            })
        }
        else
        {
        if(typeof value === 'object')
        {
            Object.entries(value).map(([a,v]) => this.isType(a,v))
        }
        else
        {
            console.log(attr);
            console.log(value);
            return(<Grid.Column><Label>{attr}</Label>{value}</Grid.Column>);
        }
        }
    };

    render()
    {
        const { data} = this.state;

        //I also tried to do the recursive map in a component, but it does not work either
        /*
        return(
        <div>
        <Grid container columns = {10}>
        <TypeComponent attr = {""} value = {data} />
        </Grid>
        </div>
        );*/

        return(
        <div>
        <Grid container columns = {10}>
        {this.isType("",data)}
        </Grid>
        </div>
        );
        
    }
}

export default raceWindow
```

When I tried to map it manually in the first layer, only first layer components rendered. Nested data in deeper layers do not render, though console output the deeper data correctly. So I assume react do not render deeper component. How should I deal with this?

Edit: Just note, I may be wrong, but I think every loop of `isType()` will go to this part of code at last:

```
else
      {
            console.log(attr);
            console.log(value);
            return(<Grid.Column><Label>{attr}</Label>{value}</Grid.Column>);
      }
```

console also output all non-array, non-object value in the log, but return() in this block does not render.

Comment: What is the end result you are trying to achieve? One big problem is that your `isType` function doesn't actually return anything in those first two if blocks. You do some kind of `Object.entries` function and then nothing happens with it. Maybe you want to create a variable to ultimately return from that function and set the value of that variable equal to the return value of those `Object.entries` functions?

Comment: I want to get all {property: "some string"} pairs in the JSON. As you can see, some are nested, ie. '"ability_bonuses"` is an array, `"starting_proficiency_options"` is an object. My logic is: 1. check if it s an array or object 2.if it is, then get elements inside it, then check these elements one by one 3.if not, then it must be string or number, show it on the page

Comment: For example, I want to show `"index": "con"`, `"name": "CON"`, `"url": "/api/ability-scores/con"` and `"bonus": 2` on the page. The first 3 belongs to `"ability_score"`, both `"ability_score"` and  `"bonus": 2` are inside "ability_bonuses".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's look at the main problems you have right now:

1. The if blocks inside your `isType` function do not return anything. You are running functions against the `value` argument, but then you're not doing anything with what those functions return. Fixing this can be as simple as changing `value.map...` to `value = value.map...`, but if you don't do *something*, then when you get to the return at the end, those if blocks will have no impact on the final result.
2. Inside the first if block, your `value.map...` function doesn't return anything since you have brackets around `Object.entries...`. You just need to `return Object.entries...`, or else remove the brackets.

If we fix those problems and simplify the if/else logic a bit, we end up getting something back in the JSX:

```
  isType(attr, value) {
    let returnValue = value;
    if (Array.isArray(returnValue)) {
      returnValue = value.map((v) => {
        return Object.entries(v).map(([a1, v1]) => this.isType(a1, v1));
      });
    } else if (typeof returnValue === "object") {
      returnValue = Object.entries(value).map(([a, v]) => this.isType(a, v));
    }
    return (
      <Grid.Column>
        <Label>{attr}</Label>
        {returnValue}
      </Grid.Column>
    );
  }
```

But you'll see when you get this far that the resulting DOM probably isn't what you want.

Instead, I recommend changing the approach a bit so that we first convert our JSON into a structure we can use and then map over it in our render function. This will hopefully also make it a little easier to reason about what is happening when and to modify your function to only add things to the final output that you actually care about.

That'd look something like this:

```
class RaceWindow extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // your JSON; store in state if necessary
    this.data = {};

    // create a placeholder variable
    this.finalDom = [];

    // call `this.isType` to fill in that variable
    // the result is a giant array of shape {attr: 'str', value: 'str'}
    this.isType("", this.state.data);
  }

  isType(attr, value) {
    if (typeof value === "string") {
      this.finalDom.push({
        attr,
        value
      });
    }
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      this.finalDom.push({
        attr,
        value: value.map((v) => {
          return Object.entries(v).map(([a1, v1]) => this.isType(a1, v1));
        })
      });
    }
    if (typeof value === "object") {
      this.finalDom.push({
        attr,
        value: Object.entries(value).map(([a, v]) => this.isType(a, v))
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div class="container">
          {this.finalDom.map((obj) => (
            <div class="item">
              <div class="label">{obj.attr}</div>
              {obj.value}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[CodeSandbox demo of the above](https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-sunset-c0s9e?file=/src/styles.css).

Final note: Make sure you capitalize the first letter of your component, or else React won't recognize it as a component.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you answer is very detail and helpful. Now I understand my conceptual problems.

Answer (score 0):

Following is working code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { Grid, Header, Label } from 'semantic-ui-react'

import TypeComponent from './type_component'
import TestComponent from './test_component'

class raceWindow extends Component {
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            data: {}
        }
    }

    componentDidMount()
    {
        fetch(this.props.hdAPI)
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then(data => {this.setState({data: data})});
        this.setState({hdAPI: this.props.hdAPI});
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps)
    {
        if(this.props.hdAPI !== prevProps.hdAPI)
        {
            fetch(this.props.hdAPI)
            .then(response=>response.json())
            .then(data => {this.setState({data: data})});
            this.setState({hdAPI: this.props.hdAPI});
        }
    }

    isType (attr, value, obj)
    {
        if(Array.isArray(value))
        {
            value.map((v) => {
                Object.entries(v).map(([a1,v1]) => this.isType(a1,v1,obj))
            })
        }
        else
        {
        if(typeof value === 'object')
        {
            Object.entries(value).map(([a,v]) => this.isType(a,v,obj))
        }
        else
        {
            var pair = {}
            pair[attr] = value
            obj.push(pair);
        }
        }
    };

    render()
    {
        const { data} = this.state;
        var obj = [];

        return(
        <div>
        <Grid container columns = {5}>
        {this.isType("",data,obj)}
        {
            obj.map((arr, i) => {
                return(
                    Object.entries(arr).map(([a,v]) => {
                    return(
                        <Grid.Column key = {i}><Label key = {i} color = 'orange'>{a}</Label>{v}</Grid.Column>
                        );
                })
                    );
            })
        }
        </Grid>
        </div>
        );
        
    }
}

export default raceWindow
```

Thanks cjl750's advice, I use an variable to collect results from recursive function and it works. I also tried to let very if block has a return as his advice, but components still do not render. Not sure why.

For now, it seems jsx returned from deep layer in recursive function do not render.

Comment: Looks like you got fairly close to what I was about to post on your own, but since you're still having some trouble, hopefully my answer can help.